# In OpenLayers 6, remove or rub drawing features like any photo editing application

Tags: map-drawing, openlayers

I am working on application where user can do drawing and change color, stroke, fill and perform undo, redo.

One feature is user should have option to rub/remove features like Photoshop or paint.
Currently OpenLayers provides a functionality of removing the whole feature. For example, if I want to remove a circle, I click on rubber and then click on circle. It will get remvoed.

But the requirement is a rubber should be like freehand and user should rub some parts of circle/any drawing or fully remove it.

I am thinking of using image instead of vector layer.

After looking into the OpenLayers 6 API, it comes with VectorImage and drawing is working fine with that but I am not sure if this is achievable easily or I have to do it in a complex way by detect the click and feature and breaking down the feature but in that case user can rub a single circle into 100s parts so I am not sure about that too.

I have not started implementing this feature so no code yet. I am just thinking of where and how to start.

Answer (score 1):

Going with a vector layer is entirely doable, you'll just have to use a library like [turf.js](https://turfjs.org/) to check on every click/drag which features are intersecting, and modify them accordingly (e.g. substract a circle). There are indeed some edge cases to handle like avoiding very small geometries to stick around. Also after a while you may end up with a *lot* of data on your map, which may or may not be a problem down the line.

You could also consider using a bitmap covering an area which you would then modify using the [Canvas2D API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D) for instance. This might be a bit more tricky to set up, and this will have limitations since your bitmap will cover a finite area at a fixed resolution, so zooming in or out too much will make this solution pointless.

To answer your question of whether this is achievable easily, the answer is no, unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will think of implementing the first one. I will have to save the drawing against each user so will keep that in mind. and we can avoid very small geometries while drawing by setting the tolerance but yeah its not easy to decide what to keep (very small geom left) while erasing freehand.